# C# inheritance does not seem to be working properly

Tags: c#, inheritance, null

I'm working on learning C# and I've ran into a problem with an example in my book.
I cant figure out why it sets my Room objets Exit to the appropriate Loactions, but my RoomWithDoor.Exits to null.

```
    public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                CreateObjects();
                MoveToANewLocation(livingRoom);
            }
            public void CreateObjects()
            {
                livingRoom = new RoomWithDoor("living room", "an antique carpet", "an oak door with a brass knob");
                livingRoom.Exits = new Locations[] { diningRoom, kitchen };
                livingRoom.DoorLocation = frontYard;

                diningRoom = new Room("dining room", "crystal chandelier");
                diningRoom.Exits = new Locations[] { livingRoom, kitchen };

    abstract class Locations
    {
        public Locations(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Locations[] Exits;
        private string name;
        public string Name { get { return name; } }

class Room : Locations
{
    public Room(string name, string decoration)
        : base(name)
    {
        this.decoration = decoration;
    }
class RoomWithDoor : Room, IHasExteriorDoor
{
    public RoomWithDoor(string name, string decoration, string doorDescription)
        : base(name, decoration)
    {
        this.doorDescription = doorDescription;
    }
```

So, this works

```
private void MoveToANewLocation(Locations newLocation)
        {
    currentLocation = newLocation;
            currentLocationExit = currentLocation.Exits[0];
            MessageBox.Show(diningRoom.Name);
```

but this dose not

```
    MessageBox.Show(livingRoom.Exits[0].Name);
```

Comment: `C# inheritance does not seem to be working properly` Yes it's buggy :)

Comment: Inheritance is working great. Your indentation however sucks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
livingRoom = new RoomWithDoor("living room", "an antique carpet", "an oak door with a brass knob");
livingRoom.Exits = new Locations[] { diningRoom, kitchen };
livingRoom.DoorLocation = frontYard;

diningRoom = new Room("dining room", "crystal chandelier");
diningRoom.Exits = new Locations[] { livingRoom, kitchen };
```

This doesn't work as you expect. Since you assign a new value to `diningRoom` after you assign `livingRoom.Exits`, `livingRoom.Exits` will still have the value `diningRoom` had at the time of assignment, which is likely `null`.

Answer (score 1):

you add dining room to your living room's exits before you have initialised dining room...

Create both dining room and living room then set the exits using the objects you have created, otherwise they will be null, as you will set the exit to be a reference to a null object then set the dining room reference to be the new object